# Can't border the way I want because of padding

Tags: html, css

Here's what's happening : [image: The result]

code :(Html)

```
<ul class="menu"  style="
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>News</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

code:(Css)

```
.menu {

list-style-type: none;

background-color: #B7FFED;

font-size: 70px;

display: inline-block;

font-family: 'Lilita One', cursive;

padding: 0px;

height: 1000px;

}



.menu li{  

padding-bottom: 100px;    
padding-top: 10px;
border: 2px solid;

}
```

I want this to be able to only border the words but to not have huge gaps. Here is a picture of what I want: [image: The thing I want]

Comment: change padding with margin

Comment: ohh Yeah right it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `margin` instead of `padding` and add `overflow: hidden`, so that your margins do not collapse:

```css
.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #B7FFED;
  font-size: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lilita One', cursive;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu li {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does collapse mean?

Comment: i was sure he will ask you the question :) btw i don't think we will have the issue in this case

Comment: I figured out what collapse means now but the help is good thanks for the help. Although i was kinda dumb

Answer (score 0):

I only had to change padding to margin to make it happen..

Comment: Yep, check my answer for another option to use `overflow: hidden` as well.